# How to edit ASP.net "form"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.net, but I am comfortable with VB.net. I have a need to do a simple edit of an existing ASP.net web page. All I need to do is add a check box. I know how to handle the code end of the issue, but coming from VB, I don't understand what I need to do to edit the actual form in the designer view. In VB I'd just open the toolbox and drag a check box over. On this ASP.net form, it seems like everything is contained in a table and I can't click on anything. If I click on one of the existing checkboxes, the whole area highlights and a tab appears that says "asp:Table". I can drag a checkbox on top of this mess, but that doesn't help.

How do I "unlock" the table's contents for editing? There has to be something stupid that I am missing.

I have attached a sample picture of an example. Say I wanted to move the "Done" box, or edit the body text. If I click on it, I just get the table properties. How do I make changes to the contents?

[image: ASP Example Picture]

This is being edited on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Learn to edit the markup rather than graphically manipulate things. Use source view instead of design view. There should be a set of tabs that switch between the views at the bottom of your editor window. Using the Split view may help you make the transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding it to the source code of the ASP page.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
```

TIP: If you click the table element on design view, then click the source tab, it should take you to the correct place in the source where the table is located.

Comment: Ahh, so it's not really a WYSIWYG-type thing? I added the checkbox as you suggested and it showed up. I can move it by regular ol' HTML-type magic. I think I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @SyntaxError To be honest i've never used the WYSIWYG :). If this solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer :)